# Scheduling All Intervals: Interesting case

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I am reading Algorithm Design by Tardos and Kleinberg. Consider the following variant of Scheduling all intervals that I came up with:

- Sort all intervals according to the non-decreasing order of finishing times (break ties arbitrarily)
- For each interval *i* in the order

  - If there exists at least one processor that can process interval *i*

    - Choose the processor *P* that can process *i* with the latest finish time (break ties arbitrarily)
    - Assign *i* to processor *P*
  - Else

    - Add a new processor and assign *i* to the newly added processor

Does this look like an optimal solution? I have not been able to come up with a counter-example for this algorithm. I tried proving this but I couldn't. Can someone come up with a counter-example to this algorithm or does this seem optimal?

Comment: Possible solution: check in Cormen.

Comment: @xenteros Could you post it here if you have the book?